# Can I block redirecting my request to mobile site when crawling?

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, web-crawler, axios

I'm trying to crawl data from a website using axios.
It works on pc, but doesn't get any data on mobile.

I found it's redirected to a mobile site which has different templates.

I've tried to set `user-agent` as pc, but it seems it's automatically changed to mobile.

```
async function getData(url) {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url:  url, 
    headers: {
      'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36'
    }
  })
    .then((response) => ...)
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try passing

```
headers: {
  'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
  'viewport-width' : 1536,
  'viewport-height' : 763
}
```

Comment: Ah, I get CORS error... 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at {{URL}} from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.